# Get properly sized brand logos in a carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive, owl-carousel

I'm trying to achieve an automatic resizing of different brand logos for a company website I'm designing, inside an [Own Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/). The idea is for each logo to be of reasonable size.

Most of the logos are in SVG formats, available at https://wetransfer.com/downloads/44eb123d186e30519edc2d025dafd03420200110231646/112373 (for a week) : as you would see, they have a wide range of height / width ratio, so using a fixed-width and enforcing the correct ratio made some of them (the CNRS and CEA logos) too high.

The goal (taken from [a random site](https://mailchimp.com/)):
[The goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9AnR.jpg)

What I got:
[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2tqd.jpg)

My code (HTML, then CSS based on Bootstrap 4, then the JS snippet that uses owl-carousel):

```
     <div class="site-section">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row justify-content-center text-center mb-5">
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <h2 class="section-heading">Ils nous ont fait confiance</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="owl-carousel clients-carousel">
                <img src="./img/clients/airbus-group.svg" class="client-logo limit-width" />
                <img src="./img/clients/safran-group.png" class="client-logo limit-width" />
                <img src="./img/clients/cnrs-fr.svg" class="client-logo limit-height" />
                <img src="./img/clients/cea-fr.svg" class="client-logo limit-height" />
                <img src="./img/clients/bic.svg" class="client-logo limit-width" />
                <img src="./img/clients/edf.svg" class="client-logo limit-width" />
                <img src="./img/clients/horiba.svg" class="client-logo limit-width" />
                <img src="./img/clients/jenoptec-group.svg" class="client-logo limit-width" />
                <img src="./img/clients/otis.svg" class="client-logo limit-width" />
                <img src="./img/clients/thales.svg" class="client-logo limit-width" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
.clients-carousel .owl-stage-outer, .clients-carousel .owl-stage, .clients-carousel .owl-item {
  display: flex;
}
.clients-carousel .owl-item {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.clients-carousel .owl-item img.client-logo {
  width: 15em;
  height: auto;
}
```

```
var siteOwlCarousel = function() {
    $('.clients-carousel').owlCarousel({
          center: true,
        items: 3,
        loop: true,
        margin: 0,
        autoplay: true,
        smartSpeed: 1000,
      nav:false,
      dots:false,
      autoWidth:true,
      responsive: {
        // breakpoint from 0 up
        0 : {
          items: 3
        },
        // breakpoint from 576 up
        576 : {
          items: 3
        },
        // breakpoint from 768 up
        768 : {
          items: 4,
          center: false
        },
        992 : {
          items: 4,
          center: false
        },
        1200 : {
          items: 4,
          center: false
        }
      }
        });
  };
  siteOwlCarousel();
```

Would somebody have an idea that relies on Flexbox?

Thanks in advance!

choumat

Comment: can you share a working snippet for this, it will be easier to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change *.owl-wrapper* display property and *owl-item* display, float, vertical-align properties and set to **max-** *width & height* size.

I hope below snippet will help you lot.

```js
var siteOwlCarousel = function() {
  $('.clients-carousel').owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    items: 3,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    autoplay: true,
    smartSpeed: 1000,
    nav: false,
    dots: false,
    autoWidth: true,
    responsive: {
      0 : {
        items: 2
      },
      576 : {
        items: 3
      },
      768 : {
        items: 4
      },
      992 : {
        items: 4
      },
      1200 : {
        items: 4
      }
    }
  });
};
siteOwlCarousel();
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper {
  display: table!important;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  display: table-cell!important;
  float: none!important;
  vertical-align: middle!important;
}
.clients-carousel .owl-item .item{
  text-align: center!important;
  padding: 15px 30px!important;
}
.clients-carousel .owl-item img{
  max-width: 180px!important;
  max-height: 50px!important;
  display: inline-block!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="site-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center text-center mb-5">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Ils nous ont fait confiance</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="owl-carousel clients-carousel">
          <div class="item"><img src="./img/clients/airbus-group.svg"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="./img/clients/safran-group.png"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="./img/clients/cnrs-fr.svg"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="./img/clients/cea-fr.svg"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="./img/clients/bic.svg"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="./img/clients/edf.svg"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="./img/clients/horiba.svg"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="./img/clients/jenoptec-group.svg"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="./img/clients/otis.svg"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="./img/clients/thales.svg"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```